# Assigning a value from an async function to object property

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

Similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55593285/i-want-to-return-the-value-of-async-function-in-object) question, I am in need of the following:

```
// foo.js

import { someAsyncFunc } from './funcs.js';

export default {
    ..., // a bunch of preset properties
    someProp: await someAsyncFunc()
}
```

Now I know to use `await` we must be in the `async` scope, unless using top-level which I cannot given the project configuration. In the linked question, the solution given is as such:

```
const promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve('myvalue');
});
const a = async() => {
  var b = await promise1
  return b;
}

const printData = async() => {
  const newobj = {
    'a': await a()
  };
  console.log(newobj)
}

printData()
```

Which does in fact resolve to `const newobj = { ... }` but only outputs to the console; the problem I'm trying to solve is getting that `newobj` out of the `printData()` call, back to the module level so that it can be exported.

All of my attempts from many SO posts, and attempts using IIFE's at the top-level have all resulted in returned `Promise` objects as expected from `async` functions.

Is there a way to get that final object out of the `async` scope so that it can be exported?

Comment: Importing is synchronous, it won't wait for the asynchronous function. You should return the promise, and use `await` in the program that imports.